# How would I make my conditional format formulas more dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Top10()

Dim rngRows As Range, rngCols As Range

LastRow = Range("CA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rngRows = Range("CA" & LastRow + 1)
Set rngCols = rngRows & columns.count

End Sub
```

I'm trying to insert a subtotal formula in my offset +1 row of column CA, and have it extend to column DO (last column).

How would I update this to do that?

How can I also change this to reflect those dynamic rows/columns?

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=CA$50452>=LARGE($CA$50452:$DO$50452,10)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).Set
```

How would I implement the lastrow/lastcolumn stuff in the conditional formatting code?

Comment: One post = one question.  Please limit your post to one question.  Who knows the first may answer the second.

Comment: What is `Set rngCols = rngRows & columns.count` supposed to return? This will most certainly throw an error.

Comment: @ScottCraner I lumped the two because they're part of the same over-arching question. It's just me asking how I would retype it to say offset +1 past last row (which I have), but then autofill that row to the last column

Comment: @dwirony That was just an example, I know it would throw an error, but how would I type up something similar to autofill that subtotal formula across that lastrow range?

Comment: You have not given enough to answer the second.

Comment: @ScottCraner pretty much I just was curious about how I would replace something like `$CA$50462:$DO50462` with a dynamic range so it can find that range regardless of how many rows end up in the report on a daily basis. I'm just trying to remove the row referencing and make it more flexible

Comment: @nicklanta look how I did it with the formula in my answer, it should answer that question.

Comment: @ScottCraner so this: `Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
'        "=ws.Cells(Lastrow + 1>=LARGE(ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol,10))"`?

it says invalid procedure/argument

Comment: you need to remove the vba parts from the string and concatenate them using `&`  Like: `"=SUM(CA2:CA" & LastRow & ")"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer to the first:

```
Sub Top10()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("CA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim LastCol As Long
LastCol = ws.Cells(LastRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'This will sum everything from row 2 to the last used row.
'Change the 2 in the formula to your first row.
ws.Range(ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, "CA"), ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol)).Formula = "=SUM(CA2:CA" & LastRow & ")"

End Sub
```